# Probability of 4 balls in one of 80 bins after 26 throws

Tags: probability, balls-in-bins

This relates to a stock problem:
I have a product with 80 sizes, the stock level of each size is 3, I forecast 26 customers per week so what is the probability I will run out of stock of at least one size ie. have an order for at east 4 of at least one size.
From this I would like to be able to try various combinations of stock level and forecast customers.

Comment: @saulspatz: as I understand it, the stock contains $80 \cdot 3$ items, and $26$ are sold per week

Comment: @GCab You're right, I read it backwards!

Comment: Is a customer equally likely to want any of the $80$ items?  Aren't some more popular than others?  One would have to know the relative likelihoods.

Comment: Are you assuming that each customer only buys 1 item, or should it read "I forecast sales of 26 items per week"?  Also as @saulspatz says, this will vary with what the items are.  If you're selling 10 different styles of t-shirt, in 8 different sizes each, then you are more likely to sell out of Medium size shirts than you are to sell out of XXXXL.

Comment: assuming "$n$ customer /w = items sold /w", and assuming equal probability per size, then your problem is equivalent to the number of ways to compose a word, of lenght $n$ (26), from the alphabet $\{1, \cdots,r\}$ (80), that does not have any character repeated more than $m$ times (3).

Answer (score 2):

For practical purposes, the probability that this happens for more than one size is so low that you can just take the expected number of sold-out sizes as an excellent approximation of the probability that at least one size is sold out. With $n=80$, $m=26$, $k=4$, this is

\begin{eqnarray*}
n\left(1-n^{-m}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\binom mj(n-1)^{m-j}\right)
&=&
80\left(1-\frac{79^{26}+26\cdot79^{25}+\binom{26}2\cdot79^{24}+\binom{26}3\cdot79^{23}}{80^{26}}\right)
\\
&\approx&
0.0234\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

If you want to know the exact probability, you can find it using [inclusion–exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) , but the calculation would be tedious since you'd have to sum over many possibilities for each of the sold-out sizes. Another way to find the exact probability would be to model this as a [Markov chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain), where the states would be characterized by the number of sizes that have $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$ items left; the number of states would be the number $\binom{80+3}3=91881$ of ways to distribute the $80$ sizes over the $4$ stock values, so this could easily be modeled exactly on a computer.

Comment: This looks reasonable to me, but I get a wildly different result.  Please take a look at my answer.

Comment: Simulation shows my answer is completely wrong.  I'm going to re-think it.

Comment: BTW, the simulations confirm your solution.

Comment: @saulspatz: The problem is that you're treating the balls as indistinguishable and thus significantly boosting the probability for them to be in the same bin. E.g. if there were $2$ bins, you'd make it equally likely that half the balls are in each bin as that they're all in one bin.

Comment: Thanks, but I simply can't see why they *ought* to be distinguishable.  I probably just have my head on backwards this morning; I'll have to think about it.  I may post a question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for this.
For clarification each customer takes just one size and the sizes are all equally likely to be taken.
From the answer it seems 2.3% probability I will not be able to supply at least one size in one week, ie demand of 4 is higher than supply.
By changing m to say 52 I could calculate for 2 weeks assuming no resupply.

Comment: @Beefos: Yes, all of that is correct.

Comment: Oh yes, I see now.  I'm counting all the distributions as equiprobable.  I really do have my head screwed on wrong!

Comment: @saulspatz: By the way, there's a further problem with your calculation: You're assuming that there are exactly $4$ balls in the sold-out buckets -- but there could be more.

Comment: No, I'm sure that's not right.  After I put $4$ balls in a bucket, I distribute the remaining balls to all $80$ buckets, so some could go in the bucket that already has $4$.